# What is the best way to compare the numerical solution to the exact solution?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, error-function

I have 2000 approximate solutions (2000 arrays of points (x,y)). In the following figure, I have randomly shown three approximate solutions versus the exact solution. By increasing the case number, the approximate solution is converging to the exact.

In this case, I want to compute Case 1, Case 2 and Case 3 error respect to the exact and show it with a single value for each case. As expected, the error should be reduced by increasing the number of cases.

What is the best way to calculate this error?

Is there a way to compare these solutions?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzmSH.png)

Comment: One way is to compute $\int_0^{50}|f_i(x)-f(x)|dx$.  Or $\sqrt{\int_0^{50}(f_i(x)-f(x))^2dx}$.  Or $\sup_{x \in [0,50]} |f_i(x)-f(x)|$.  Related:  $L_1$ norm, $L_2$ norm, $L_{\infty}$ norm.

Comment: But watch out for the [Gibbs phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon) at that jump. Depending on the error metric you choose, it will either be washed out in the error, so the error won't reflect how bad the situation is at the jump, or will dominate the error, so the error doesn't reflect how good the situation is everywhere else.

Comment: Dear @Michael , thank you for the information, I modified my code and compute error by using the equation: $\int_0^{50}|f_(x)-fa(x)|dx / \int_0^{50}|f(x)|dx$. It is apparent from the result that the error decreased by increasing case number, but in some cases, a slight increase was observed respect to their previous case, for example, the error in case 314 and 315 is 2.37% and 2.45% respectively. are these jumps normal?

Comment: Dear @Paul , Thank you for your kind attention.

Comment: @ImanBazeghi : Impossible to tell if we don't know anything about what is being approximated, or how.  If this is a Fourier approximation then the L2 norm should get better and better.  Perhaps there can be non-monotonic behavior with the L1 norm that you are using, that is kind of an interesting observation.